# Angular on EventEmitter @input data clear getting error in schema form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

when the form submitted, getting error from form as `Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

```
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  VERSION,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

import { FormSchema } from '../form.schema';

@Component({
  selector: 'shared-form',
  templateUrl: './shared.form.html',
})
export class SharedForm implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() schema = FormSchema;
  @Output() userFormOnSubmit = new EventEmitter();
  userForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // this.schema.forEach((item) => {
    //   if (item.formControl === item.controlName) {
    //     this.userForm.get(item.controlName).setValue(item.value);
    //   }
    // });
  }
  updateForm($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.userFormOnSubmit.emit(this.userForm.value);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('callss');
  }
}
```

template:

```
<div>
  {{schema|json}}
  <form [formGroup]="userForm" (submit)="updateForm($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let element of schema">
      <label>{{ element.name }}</label>
      <input [type]="'element.type'" [formControlName]="element.formControl" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

How to fix this? do not know why the `@input()` value cleared. any correct way to update the value to parent.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9vh5nh?file=src/app/shared/shared.form.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in using the map method — you need to return a value:

```js
this.newFormSchema = this.newFormSchema.map((item) => {
  item.value = update[item.name] + new Date();
  return item; // !
});
```

Also, here you can use `forEach`:

```js
this.newFormSchema.forEach((item) => {
  item.value = update[item.name] + new Date();
});
```

Comment: I updated, it works. but why do not I update the value by manual? can you help me

Comment: This is how `map` works, if no value is returned then `undefined` is written. Btw, you can use `forEach` here, I will update the answer.

Comment: map only works fine. I am finding the issue here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9vh5nh?file=src/app/shared/shared.form.ts at ` updateValue(controlName) {}` if I remove the iteration then it's editable. but I need to set the values from schema. how to set the value from schema?